# Add legends to chart

Tags: c#, excel, excel-charts

I have a Excel chart. How do I add a legend value?

```
  Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
  Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);

  Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
  chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("B12", "B15");  
  chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
  chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xl3DPieExploded;
  foreach (Series series in chartPage.SeriesCollection())
  {
      series.Name = "Diagram Name";
  }

  chartPage.HasLegend = true;
  chartPage.Is

  //export chart as picture file
  String destPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
  chartPage.Export(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\dig2.bmp", "BMP", misValue);
```

Method "Series" not available.

Comment: Is the last text line an error message you are getting?

Comment: I not got a error. I need a legend diagram.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  I added in some data so the example would work stand alone.

```
Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

Workbook xlWorkBook;
Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlWorkSheet.Name = "Sheet";

ChartObjects xlCharts = (ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
ChartObject myChart = (ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);

Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

chartPage.Legend.Position = XlLegendPosition.xlLegendPositionBottom;
chartPage.HasTitle = true;
chartPage.ChartTitle.Text = "Title";

xlWorkSheet.Cells[12, 1] = "Test";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[13, 1] = "Test2";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[14, 1] = "Test3";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[15, 1] = "Test4";
xlWorkSheet.Cells[12, 2] = 12;
xlWorkSheet.Cells[13, 2] = 13;
xlWorkSheet.Cells[14, 2] = 14;
xlWorkSheet.Cells[15, 2] = 15;



var sc = chartPage.SeriesCollection();
var series1 = sc.NewSeries();
series1.Name = "Title";
series1.XValues = $"'{xlWorkSheet.Name}'!A12:A15";
series1.Values = $"'{xlWorkSheet.Name}'!B12:B15";
series1.ChartType = XlChartType.xl3DPieExploded;
chartPage.ApplyDataLabels();

//export chart as picture file
String destPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
chartPage.Export(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\dig2.bmp", "BMP", misValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 [![Excel.Range chartRange;


            Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
            Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
            Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
            //диаграмма 2
            chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("D12", "E16");
            chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
            chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xl3DPieExploded;
            foreach (Series series in chartPage.SeriesCollection())
            {
                series.Name = "Уровень удовлетворенности респондентов длительностью ожидания";
            }
            chartPage.HasLegend = true;

            //export chart as picture file
            String destPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            chartPage.ApplyDataLabels(XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowValue, false, true, false, false, false, false, true, false, false);
             chartPage.Export(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\dig2.bmp", "BMP", misValue);
            //конец диаграмы 2][1]][1]
```